# Creating new rows in df based on date range

Tags: python, pandas

Below is script for a simplified version of the df in question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020/01/07'), 
                   'id' : range(1,8), 
                   'product': ['list_3','list_1','list_2', 'list_3','list_2','list_1','list_1'],
                  'duration' : [3,1,2,3,2,1,1],
                  'product_in_use': ('true'),
                  'end_date':['2020-01-03','2020-01-02','2020-01-04','2020-01-06','2020-01-06','2020-01-06',
                                '2020-01-07']})

df['duration']= pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='D')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
df
```

df:

```
    date       id   product duration product_in_use end_date
0   2020-01-01  1   list_3  3 days     true        2020-01-03
1   2020-01-02  2   list_1  1 days     true        2020-01-02
2   2020-01-03  3   list_2  2 days     true        2020-01-04
3   2020-01-04  4   list_3  3 days     true        2020-01-06
4   2020-01-05  5   list_2  2 days     true        2020-01-06
5   2020-01-06  6   list_1  1 days     true        2020-01-06
6   2020-01-07  7   list_1  1 days     true        2020-01-07
```

As you can see in the df above, each id is using a product and each product lasts for a particular duration. There are no rows for the days when the product is in action, only rows for when the product was purchased by the user.

Therefore, I would like to create new rows, for **all** dates where the product is in use for each id.

My intended df would therefore be this:

```
    date       id   product  duration   product_in_use
0   2020-01-01  1   list_3   3 days         true
1   2020-01-02  1   list_3   3 days         true
2   2020-01-03  1   list_3   3 days         true
3   2020-01-02  2   list_1   1 days         true
4   2020-01-03  3   list_2   2 days         true
5   2020-01-04  3   list_2   2 days         true
6   2020-01-04  4   list_3   3 days         true
7   2020-01-05  4   list_3   3 days         true
8   2020-01-06  4   list_3   3 days         true
9   2020-01-05  5   list_2   3 days         true
10  2020-01-06  5   list_2   2 days         true
11  2020-01-06  6   list_1   2 days         true
12  2020-01-07  7   list_1   1 days         true
```

Comment: Can you check your expected output once. Is it correct? Rows 4,5,6 all have duration 2 days, is it correct?

Comment: Thank you! Output is amended, id 4's product's duration is 3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = pd.concat(pd.Series(r.Index, pd.date_range(r.date,r.end_date))
              for r in df.itertuples())

df1 = df.loc[s].assign(date=s.index).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

create date ranges from the start date to the end date for each id, using **[starmap](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)** and **[chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)**, expand the main dataframe by the duration, and assign the new dates as index of the dataframe.

```
from itertools import starmap,chain

#create date ranges from date to end_date for each id
start_end = zip(df.date.array,df.end_date.array)
date_ranges = starmap(pd.date_range,start_end)
date_ranges = chain.from_iterable(date_ranges)

#get all columns except date and end_date
res = df.filter(['id','product','duration','product_in_use'])

#expand the dataframe by repeating the indexes based on the duration
#so index 0 will be repeated 3 times, 1 once, 2 twice, ...
res = res.reindex(res.index.repeat(res.duration.dt.days))

#assign the new date_ranges to the dataframe
res.index = date_ranges
res

           id   product duration    product_in_use
2020-01-01  1   list_3    3 days    true
2020-01-02  1   list_3    3 days    true
2020-01-03  1   list_3    3 days    true
2020-01-02  2   list_1    1 days    true
2020-01-03  3   list_2    2 days    true
2020-01-04  3   list_2    2 days    true
2020-01-04  4   list_3    3 days    true
2020-01-05  4   list_3    3 days    true
2020-01-06  4   list_3    3 days    true
2020-01-05  5   list_2    2 days    true
2020-01-06  5   list_2    2 days    true
2020-01-06  6   list_1    1 days    true
2020-01-07  7   list_1    1 days    true
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a different `DataFrame`, then execute an outer join to add the new rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not convert 'duration' field to timedelta then this worked for me:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for idx in df.index:
    print(idx, df['duration'][idx])
    for i in range(df['duration'][idx]):
        temp_df = df[idx:idx+1]
        temp_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['date']) + timedelta(days=i)
        df1 = df1.append(temp_df)

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1.drop(['end_date', 'index'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
         date  id product  duration product_in_use
0  2020-01-01   1  list_3         3           true
1  2020-01-02   1  list_3         3           true
2  2020-01-03   1  list_3         3           true
3  2020-01-02   2  list_1         1           true
4  2020-01-03   3  list_2         2           true
5  2020-01-04   3  list_2         2           true
6  2020-01-04   4  list_3         3           true
7  2020-01-05   4  list_3         3           true
8  2020-01-06   4  list_3         3           true
9  2020-01-05   5  list_2         2           true
10 2020-01-06   5  list_2         2           true
11 2020-01-06   6  list_1         1           true
12 2020-01-07   7  list_1         1           true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your message! I received this error message though unfortunately `TypeError: 'Timedelta' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: I modified the solution. Also can you verify your expected output once if it is correct. I think for each duration there would be equally same count of rows. That is not happening in your expected output example

Comment: Thank you! Output amended as per comment under question