# Python: Create new rows based on difference between date values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm trying to create new records based on the difference between the first and second record, and from the second to the third, per Id, and so on.
pandas.diff() and pandas.shift() did not did the trick besides telling me the total difference in days between the first and second record etc.

Following the posted solution [Creating new rows in df based on date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929314/creating-new-rows-in-df-based-on-date-range) here did not work, since there is no end date in my dataset.

Suppose the following dataset:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id','Code','Date'])
Ids=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]
Codes=[8,9,11,5,6,7,8,7,8]
Dates=['2020-07-02','2020-06-16','2020-04-07',
      '2020-02-19','2020-03-18','2020-05-02','2020-07-02',
      '2020-05-19','2020-03-24']
df1.Id=Ids
df1.Code=Codes
df1.Date=Dates
```

```
Id  Code    Date
1   8   2020-07-02
1   9   2020-06-16
1   11  2020-04-07
2   5   2020-02-19
2   6   2020-03-18
2   7   2020-05-02
2   8   2020-07-02
3   7   2020-05-19
3   8   2020-03-24
```

The result I would like to achieve is:

```
Id  Code    Date
1   8   2020-07-02
1   9   2020-06-16
1   11  2020-05-01
1   11  2020-04-07
2   5   2020-02-19
2   6   2020-03-18
2   7   2020-04-01
2   7   2020-05-02
2   8   2020-06-01
2   8   2020-07-02
3   7   2020-05-19
3   8   2020-04-01
3   11  2020-03-24
```

As you can see for each missing date between Date & Code a new record is made that specifies the month between the two records, and in this new record a copy from the Code is made from its previous record.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the following is optimal, but it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id','Code','Date'])
for _, df_temp in df1.groupby(by=['Id'], axis=0):
    df_temp = df_temp.sort_values(by=['Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
    # impute values
    dates = df_temp['Date']
    for i in range(df_temp.shape[0] - 1):
        date_range = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in pd.date_range(dates.loc[i], dates.loc[i+1], freq='M')]
        new_rows = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id','Code','Date'])
        new_rows['Date'] = date_range
        new_rows['Id'] = df_temp.loc[i, 'Id']
        new_rows['Code'] = df_temp.loc[i, 'Code']
        df = pd.concat([df, new_rows])
    # take care of the last entry
    df.loc[df.shape[0]] = df_temp.loc[df_temp.shape[0] - 1]
```