# Efficient Method to interpolate between 2 pandas date objects?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a table that shows the months that a category of people is available, using an excel table like this one:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5rW.png)
I know that I can interpolate using the following method:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')
final = pd.DataFrame()
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    start = row['Start Date']
    end = row['End Date']
    range = pd.date_range(start,end, freq='M')
    df = pd.DataFrame(range)
    df['Name'] = str(row['Project'])
    final = pd.concat([final, df], ignore_index=True)
```

But I know that this method is very inefficient, and that there should be a more efficient way using pandas native methods, but I am unsure how to do this.
The output should look this this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftpkk.png)

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: I just updated the question to show the expected ouput

Comment: Is the `Table` image the input dataset?

Comment: It is a subset of the total dataset, I wasn't sure how else I could show a representative dataset on Stackoverflow. If there is a method where I can uploaded it then I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer, which seems to be doing the same thing you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930008/11542834